# Tracking the date of a resource's major changes on MODX3

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-resources

MODX provides fields for tracking content changes: "editedon" and "publishedon".

Publishedon contains the date and time when the resource was published. Editedon updates whenever I save a resource, regardless of the change's significance.

However, "editedon" is not ideal for displaying an "Updated On" date on the page because minor edits, like correcting typos, trigger updates.

What would be the best solution to track the date of major changes?

1. Is there any way to prevent "editedon" from updating on every save, reserving it for significant changes?
2. Or should I make a custom TV to track the date of the changes manually?
3. Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to make a custom TV to set manually the Last Update time. Preventing the *editedo*n field from updating did not feel like a good solution.